# Организация ролевой системы доступа к разделам сайта

Tags: php, mysql, меню, laravel5, доступ

На сайте есть много *ресурсных* контроллеров, штук 8, в каждом по 7 методов (`index`, `show`, `edit`, `create`, `update`, `store`, `delete`), а есть и не ресурсные, где 1-2 таких метода из списка выше.

Нужно организовать ролевую систему доступа. Понятно, что на каждый такой контроллер повесить middleware слои и тп, это ладно, не проблема. Но что делать с визуальной частью?

То есть: на сайте конечно есть меню и нужно, чтобы кто-то видел те или иные кнопки, а кто-то нет. Конечно вручную описывать все это дело не хочется, а как организовать этот момент алгоритмическим путём? Нужно также предусмотреть, чтобы из админки можно было изменить право на тот или иной раздел.

Первое, что приходит в голову - создать в базе 4 таблицы:

1. Хранить имена ресурсов, может описание там какое нибудь,
2. Хранит названия action'ов (те 7 штук выше),
3. Таблица связи для первой и второй. То есть между таблицей ресурсов и действий МхМ.
4. Таблица для ролей.
5. Таблица связи для ролей и таблицей 3.
   Но что-то это очень замороченно мне кажется.

Как грамотно организовать это разделение?